# Deformation of an elastic bar

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, elasticity

We know that if we fix a bar at one of its ends, then the other one will descend by $s = A \cdot F l^3, A = const.$ (we can assume that $F$ is the gravitational force.

```
||
---------
||
^
solidly fixed here
```

We can assume that we know the descend of the end in this case and mark it by $x$

If we put it freely, like this

```
----------
||      ||
^       ^
held here
```

Then I heard we can treat it like two bars solidly fixed in the middle (not sure why)

But what if we fix it at the both ends, like this:

```
||      ||
----------
||      ||
^       ^
solidly fixed here
```

How low will the lowest point of the bar descend?

Comment: This looks like a homework problem.  Is it?

Comment: If $F$ is gravitational force then it is applied uniformly along the beam and not at the end.

Comment: For a bar fixed at one end with gravity the deflection would be $s = A \cdot w \ell^4$ where $w$ is the unit weight of the beam (weight/length).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can see it like this. Each segment of beam between a max. curvature point and zero curvature zone will have the same deflection of the same length.

[image: pic]

For the three cases you need:

1. One segment of length $\ell$ for deflection $\delta$
2. Two segments of length $\frac{\ell}{2}$ for deflection $\delta$
3. Four segments of length $\frac{\ell}{4}$ for deflection $2 \delta$

Comment: Can you justify/prove that all parts will have the same length and the same deflection? It doesn't seem obvious.