# How to model analytical expression for spring constant $k$ for certain structure?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, stress-strain, structural-beam

[image]

In the deflection of beam, I learned that

$$
\delta y=\frac{FL^3}{3EI}
$$

where
$$
I=\frac{h^3w}{12}
$$

Together they comprise
$$
F=\frac{Eh^3w}{4L^3}\delta y
$$
How do I apply to four beams?
[image]

is it just
$$
\delta y=\frac{1}{4}\times\frac{4L^3}{Eh^3w}F
$$
?
because deflection will be decreased by number of beams?

Comment: You cannot add then like this because in the first case the beam has slope where the force is applied, and in the second it doesn't. The shape is different in these cases.

Comment: I think this question is better suited for [Engineering.SE]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add the deflections between the two cases because the overall shape is different. See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/229210/392) answer to a similar question.

> Maybe you can see it like this. Each segment of beam between a max. curvature point and zero curvature zone will have the same deflection of the same length.

[image: pic]

As you can see you have zero curvature (max slope) at the load in the first case, and max curvature (zero slope) at the load in the second case.

So in the first case if the deflection is $\delta = \frac{F \ell^3}{3 E I}$ for length $\ell$, then the deflection on the second case (with only one row of beams) is

$$\delta = \frac{F \ell^3}{192 E I}$$ because it is twice the deformation of a quarter length shared between two sides. Split the load in two (one half towards the left side and one half on the right side) and apply $\delta = 2  \left( \frac{ (F/2) (\ell/4)^3 }{3 E I} \right) $.

With two rows, the deformation is half of this because the load is shared between the two rows.

$$ \boxed{ \delta= \frac{F \ell^3}{384 E I} } $$

---

The proper way to handle these problems is to come up with the internal moment as a function of position

$$ M(x) = M_A - \frac{F}{2} \left( \frac{\ell}{2}-x \right) $$

where $M_A$ is the support moment. The find the total strain energy *for one row* of the structure considering bending only.

$$ U = 2 \int \limits_0^\frac{\ell}{2} \frac{M^2}{2 E I} \,{\rm d}x = \frac{\ell (F^2 \ell^2 + 12 F M_a \ell + 48 M_A^2)}{96 E I} $$

Now impose the no rotation constraint on the support by solving

$$ \left. \frac{\partial U}{\partial M_A}=0 \right\} M_A = - \frac{F \ell}{8} $$

and finding the displacement at the load from the principle of virtual work

$$ \delta = \frac{\partial U}{\partial F} = \frac{F \ell^3}{192 E I} \;\;\;\checkmark$$

Comment: I can see now that I had to use the model "clamped at both end"... Just one more question. How do you calculate stress at the clamped end? I know that stress is $\frac{Fl}{8Z}$, where $Z=I/z$ and $z$ is neutral axis to end, which is just $h/2$, so $\frac{Fhl}{16I}$. With two rows, do I need to just divide it half?

Comment: There are two options. I am not sure which one is more correct. a) Individually with $$\sigma = \frac{M_A \frac{h}{2}}{\frac{h^3 w}{12}}$$ or b) together with $$\sigma = \frac{2 M_A \frac{s+h}{2}}{\frac{h^3 w}{6} + \frac{h s^2 w}{2}}$$ where $s$ is the centerline separation of the two rows.